# Let $X$ be a metric space with metric $d$. Let $Y \subset X$. Give an example where $A$ is open in $Y$ but not open in $X$. Similarly for closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space with metric $d$. Let $Y \subset X$. Give an example where $A$ is open in $Y$ but not open in $X$. Give an example where $A$ is closed in $Y$ but not closed in $X$.

I'm stuck on question above in Munkres "Analysis on Manifolds" and I'm not sure I'm thinking about this correctly. For the first example, my idea for $A$ is an open ball in $Y$ and a single element in $X$ (and not $Y$). Is this the right way to be thinking about this? If not, could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Let $Y$ not be open in $X$. Then...

Comment: Think in terms of the subspace topology. For example, (0,1) as a subspace of $\mathbb R$ is closed in itself. Is it closed in $\mathbb R$? Also, can you paste the problem into your question rather than use a link?

Comment: Got rid of that link. I see how that works with closed sets but open sets seem much more difficult. If Y is not open in X, can Y still be open in itself? In that case, could I just choose A=Y?

Comment: If Y is not open in itself you don't have a topology. So yes, [0,1] as a subspace of $\mathbb R$ is open in itself.

Comment: Just to clarify, if [0,1] as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ is open, does this also imply (since it's complement is the empty set) that it is closed?

Comment: Yes. All topologies include the entire set and the empty set. Therefore, their complements, the empty set and the entire set, respectively, are also closed.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Let X=R and Y= [0,1)U(2,3]. Then Y is itself a metric space with the same metric.
Take A= [0,1), it is open in Y but not open in X, also it is closed in Y but not closed in X.